# How to pick a specific connection with mongokit?

Tags: python, django, mongokit

I'm trying to connect to a Mongo DB with Django and Mongokit (using django-mongokit). When I try to feed it a remote

In settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ['DATABASE_URL']),
    'mongodb': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ['MONGOHQ_URL']),
}
```

DATABASES is correctly populated with connection data, for what it's worth.

In the main routine:

```
from mongokit import Connection

# ...
conn = Connection('mongodb')
conn.register([Account])
db = conn.foo
collection = db.bar
```

This throws a `getaddrinfo failed` error. Connection(), it seems, wants a PymongoConnection, but I'm not sure how to get that. And when I try feeding a remote URL into DATABASES.mongodb, it freaks out as well. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Not really a solution, but I ended up just using pymongo straight rather than django-mongokit. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

`conn = Connection('mongodb')` is trying to connect to a served called literally `mongodb` - using `conn = Connection(DATABASES['mongodb'])` in whatever way you've got it set up (via `app.config`?) is going to be the way to do it.